# Modifying POST url in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Can you please explain how to use urlForCreateRecord in adapter to change the post url?
I have two model employee and tasks with one to many relationship.

```
//Employee model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    empId : DS.attr(),
    password : DS.attr(),
    email : DS.attr(),
    tasks : DS.hasMany('task')
});

//Task model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr(),
    description : DS.attr(),
    startDate : DS.attr(),
    endDate : DS.attr(),
    employee : DS.belongsTo("employee")
});
```

Now I want to create a task record. 
I am creating task record like this

```
let self=this;
let employee=this.store.peekRecord("employee",1);
let task=this.store.createRecord("task",{
    name:self.get("name"),
    description:self.get("description"),
    startDate:self.get("startDate"),
    endDate:self.get("endDate"),
    employee:employee
});
task.save();
```

The post request should go to URL like /employee/:employee_id/tasks.
But the url is getting created like /tasks.
How do I achieve the required post url?

Comment: What did you tried? What Adapter are you extending from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [customize the adapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/) of your task model.

```
ember generate adapter task
```

After that you can override one or more of the  [urlFor-methods](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/methods/urlForCreateRecord?anchor=urlForCreateRecord)

```
//app/adapters/task.js
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  urlForCreateRecord(modelName, snapshot) {
    return 'employee/7/tasks';
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I use the host that is declared in application adapter?

Comment: What do you mean? Look at the example. The task-adapter extends the ApplicationAdapter.

Comment: Ah you mean the host definition. Because of the extension host of application-adapter is used!